# How could I iterate in a nested array if a different conditions are TRUE?

Tags: perl, loops, conditional-statements, unique-key

I have this input for my program:

```
miRNA127    dvex589433  131 154 -   24  87.5    atcgtaacgtatctcccacactta    32  55  98
miRNA32 dvex320240  61  83  -   23  86.9565217391304    cttctacaatggtactgtccatt 31  53  97
miRNA32 dvex623745  141 163 -   23  86.9565217391304    ggtttcttccacaatagtaattt 26  48  97
miRNA79 dvex468096  702 733 -   32  81.25   ttggttaaaaatttttttttttaattaaaaaa    6   37  55
miRNA79 dvex468096  717 743 +   27  81.4814814814815    aaaaaatttttaaccaaagaaaaaaat 13  39  55
miRNA79 dvex468096  694 718 -   25  84  tttttttaattaaaaaacaattttt   17  41  55
miRNA79 dvex468096  696 724 +   29  75.8620689655172    aaattgttttttaattaaaaaaaaaaatt   13  41  55
miRNA79 dvex219016  1103    1130    +   28  78.5714285714286    aaatttttgctaaaaaatacaaaaattt    14  41  55
miRNA79 dvex219016  3420    3446    +   27  77.7777777777778    aaaatattattaaataaataatgcaat 13  39  55
miRNA79 dvex219016  1384    1408    +   25  80  tttcgtgaaacaaaaaagtttggaa   21  45  55
miRNA79 dvex219016  4384    4424    +   25  80  tttcgtgaaacaaaaaagtttggaa   21  45  55
miRNA154    dvex573491  297 324 +   28  78.5714285714286    cagcttgattttaagcctatctgaaagc    23  50  76
miRNA154    dvex546562  232 259 +   28  78.5714285714286    cagcttgattttaagcctatttgaaagc    23  50  76
miRNA154    dvex648254  147 172 +   26  80.7692307692308    aagcctacggagtgcgaggcagagct  47  72  76
miRNA154    dvex648254  277 303 +   26  80.7692307692308    aagcctacggagtgcgaggcagagct  47  72  76
```

I need to group if have the same $1, $2 and $5 values. Therefore I decided use a hash with different nested arrays:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'miRNA79 dvex219016 +' => [
        [ '1103', '1130', '14', '41', '55' ],
        [ '3420', '3446', '13', '39', '55' ],
        [ '1384', '1408', '21', '45', '55' ],
        [ '4384', '4424', '21', '45', '55' ]
    ],
    'miRNA79 dvex468096 +' => [
        [ '717', '743', '13', '39', '55' ],
        [ '696', '724', '13', '41', '55' ]
    ],
    'miRNA154 dvex546562 +' => [ [ '232', '259', '23', '50', '76' ] ],
    'miRNA79 dvex468096 -' => [
        [ '702', '733', '6',  '37', '55' ],
        [ '694', '718', '17', '41', '55' ]
    ],
    'miRNA154 dvex648254 +' => [
        [ '147', '172', '47', '72', '76' ],
        [ '277', '303', '47', '72', '76' ]
    ],
    'miRNA127 dvex589433 -' => [ [ '131', '154', '32', '55', '98' ] ],
    'miRNA154 dvex573491 +' => [ [ '297', '324', '23', '50', '76' ] ],
    'miRNA32 dvex320240 -'  => [ [ '61',  '83',  '31', '53', '97' ] ],
    'miRNA32 dvex623745 -'  => [ [ '141', '163', '26', '48', '97' ] ]
};
```

After that, I organized with respect to the [0]->[0] value of the nested array for each key of the hash. If the nested array has 1 array I print it. But if has 1< i need to group it. Next I show a example to group:

```
'miRNA79 dvex468096 -' => [
    [ '702', '733', '6',  '37', '55' ],
    [ '694', '718', '17', '41', '55' ]
    ],
```

Organize it:

```
$VAR1 = [ [ 696, '724', '13', '41', '55' ],
          [ 717, '743', '13', '39', '55' ] ];
```

If the difference between [1][1] and [0][0] is less or equal than [0][4] I need to combined it and generate this new array:

```
$VAR1 = [ [ 696, '743', '13', '39', '55' ], ];
```

and print it. In this case:

```
$VAR1 = [
    [ 1103, '1130', '14', '41', '55' ],
    [ 1384, '1408', '21', '45', '55' ],
    [ 3420, '3446', '13', '39', '55' ],
    [ 4384, '4424', '21', '45', '55' ]
];
```

Evaluates if  [1][1] and [0][0] is less or equal than [0][4], FALSE, so i need to extract the first one nested array and print it, and again iterate to evaluate the last condition. If it generates a TRUE value I need to combined, if the evaluation generates a FALSE value, i need to extract the firts nested array and print it. Next, my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw/ min max /;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use Math::MatrixReal;

my %data;
my $val;
my $num;
my $start;
my $end;
my $diff;
my $start_q;
my $end_q;
my @new_data;
my @extract;
my @extract2;
my $limit;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    push @{ $data{"@fields[0,1,4]"} }, [ @fields[ 2, 3, 8, 9, 10 ] ];
}

foreach my $key ( sort keys %data ) {
    $val = $data{$key};
    $num = scalar @$val;
    next if $num == 0;

    if ( $num == 1 ) {    # print if the hash have 1 nested array
        print
            "$key\t $data{$key}[0][0]\t $data{$key}[0][1]\t $data{$key}[0][2]\t $data{$key}[0][3]\t $data{$key}[0][4]\n";
    }
    else {
        foreach my $keys ( @$val[0] ) {
            my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
                @$val;    #organize the nested array values
            $start   = $sorted[0][0];
            $end     = $sorted[1][1];
            $limit   = $sorted[0][4];
            $diff    = $end - $start;
            $start_q = $sorted[0][2];
            $end_q   = $sorted[1][3];

            if ( $diff < $limit ) {
                @new_data = ();
                push( @new_data, $start );
                push( @new_data, $end );
                push( @new_data, $start_q );
                push( @new_data, $end_q );
                push( @new_data, $limit );
                @extract = splice( @{ $sorted[0] }, 0, 5, @new_data );
                @extract2 = splice( @{ $sorted[1] } );
            }
            else {
                my @toprint = splice( @{ $sorted[0] } );
                print
                    "$key\t$toprint[0]\t$toprint[1]\t$toprint[2]\t$toprint[3]\t$toprint[4]\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In general, I have this result:

```
miRNA127 dvex589433 -    131     154     32  55  98
miRNA154 dvex546562 +    232     259     23  50  76
miRNA154 dvex573491 +    297     324     23  50  76
miRNA154 dvex648254 +   147 172 47  72  76 
miRNA32 dvex320240 -     61  83  31  53  97
miRNA32 dvex623745 -     141     163     26  48  97
miRNA79 dvex219016 +    1103    1130    14  41  55
```

But in those list some values do not appear because my code don't iterates if the conditions are TRUE. Some suggestions?

Comment: Please fix the indenting of your code.  The foreach my $keys (@$val[0]){ line seems odd since I don't see you referencing $keys afterwards.

Comment: Because that $keys refers to hash keys.

Comment: If I understand this properly, you need to write a recursive function,  and store all the data until recursion is done before printing.

Comment: If I understand it properly, what you are looking for is called reduction in functional programming. In your case conditional reduction. You have the array of elements and what you want is an array with fewer elements.

Comment: Can you give us an idea what each column represents and what you are attempting to do with that information? Trying to handle various nested structures can be difficult. However, I suspect that what you're trying to do would be a lot easier if you could represent your data as objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you are trying to merge some RNA sequences (?) into one when they are near enough (result length is less than some limit). You are may be looking for code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Input data format positions
use constant KEY_FIELDS => ( 0, 1, 4 );
use constant DATA_FIELDS => ( 2, 3, 8, 9, 10 );

# Entry positions (DATA_FIELDS meanings)
use constant {
    START_P => 0,
    END_P   => 1,
    START_Q => 2,
    END_Q   => 3,
    LIMIT   => 4
};

# Output formatter
use constant TO_PRINT => START_P .. LIMIT;

sub format_entry {
    my ( $key, $data ) = @_;
    join "\t", $key, @$data[TO_PRINT];
}

# Read Data
my %data;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    push @{ $data{"@fields[KEY_FIELDS]"} }, [ @fields[DATA_FIELDS] ];
}

# Transform data to keep only records supposed to appear in output
for my $value ( values %data ) {
    my @entries = sort { $a->[START_P] <=> $b->[START_P] } @$value;
    my @result = ( shift @entries );    # add first one as reference
    while (@entries) {
        my $ref   = $result[-1];        # reference entry
        my $entry = shift @entries;
        if ( $entry->[END_P] - $ref->[START_P] < $ref->[LIMIT] ) {

            # merge entry into reference
            @$ref[ END_P, END_Q ] = @$entry[ END_P, END_Q ];
        }
        else {
            push @result, $entry;
        }
    }
    $value = \@result;                  # rewrite value in %data hash
}

# Write output
for my $key ( sort keys %data ) {
    print format_entry( $key, $_ ), "\n" for @{ $data{$key} };
}
```

The result for data in your question is:

```
miRNA127 dvex589433 -   131     154     32      55      98
miRNA154 dvex546562 +   232     259     23      50      76
miRNA154 dvex573491 +   297     324     23      50      76
miRNA154 dvex648254 +   147     172     47      72      76
miRNA154 dvex648254 +   277     303     47      72      76
miRNA32 dvex320240 -    61      83      31      53      97
miRNA32 dvex623745 -    141     163     26      48      97
miRNA79 dvex219016 +    1103    1130    14      41      55
miRNA79 dvex219016 +    1384    1408    21      45      55
miRNA79 dvex219016 +    3420    3446    13      39      55
miRNA79 dvex219016 +    4384    4424    21      45      55
miRNA79 dvex468096 +    696     743     13      39      55
miRNA79 dvex468096 -    694     733     17      37      55
```